# Lamda function reuse best practices

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Should Lambda functions call other Lambda functions or should they be self contained?

My environment is

- Serverless Framework
- Nodejs
- AWS API Gateway
- AWS Lamda
- AWS DynamoDB

I've build several CRUD for API resources each Dynamo table and now I'm creating some specialized ones that cross tables.

If I have a function createTeamForecast, and I need to get a single row from table Team, should I import the function getTeam or just write the Dynamo query. I lean to importing the function, but I haven't see anything saying that is OK.

getTeam.js

```html
import * as dynamoDbLib from "./libs/dynamodb-lib";
import { apiResponse } from "./libs/response-lib";

export async function main(event, context, callback) {
  const params = {
    TableName: "teams",
    Key: {
      id: event.pathParameters.team_id
    }
  };

  try {
    const result = await dynamoDbLib.call("get", params);
    if (result.Item) {
      // Return the retrieved item
      callback(null, apiResponse(200,"OK",result.Item));
    } else {
      callback(null, apiResponse(404, "Team not found."));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    callback(null, apiResponse(500,'Server error',e));
  }
}
```

In my createTeamForecast, can I just import that function and then call it.

```html
import { main as getTeam } from "./getTeam";
```

My alternative is to just do a Dynamo get and check results within my createTeamForecast.js function. That's more self contained, but not very DRY.

The way that Serverless and Lambda manage the functions, it feels a little disconnected. Anyone have any pros or cons?

Comment: Not too familiar with the Serverless framework specifically but as a general rule I would personally try to complete the task within a single Lambda, so import the code, rather than invoke a 2nd Lambda (where you're paying 2x for the duration of the child Lambda, plus potentially running into difficult problems with dealing with timeout retries). Unless your model is deliberately async fan-out, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's reasonable to import the code you need from another module rather than rewriting it. This has the side benefit of making it easier to maintain your application because you won't have duplicated logic all over the place.

The trick with serverless applications is finding the balance between code re-use and separation of concerns. The specifics of how to do this are somewhat application dependent. However, if you're putting too much code into each function then it's likely that your application is too tightly coupled and could use decomposition into smaller functions that more tightly model their problem space. If you find large swaths of shared code within your Lambda functions that might be a good indicator that they should be refactored into other functions.

If you're modeling really complex business domains then you may also want to consider calling other Lambda functions from within Lambda functions or investigating AWS Step Functions which provide a state machine on top of Lambda.

Comment: That makes sense. Just wasn't sure if there was something of a moving target wither Serverless, Lamda and API Gateway. Slightly different issue, but setting up multiple evenrironments I found my policies were breaking because my Serverless changes were generating a new API key. Thought I might run into something similar.